# the sequence 1,11,111,.. and primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the sequence $\{A_n\} = 1,\, 11,\, 111,\, 1111,\, \dots\,$, where $$A_n = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} 10^k$$

I wonder if there exists an $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that for all $m>z$, $A_m$ is composite? Please do not give me a complete solution, only a hint. I wonder, for example, if the pigeonhole principle can be used to get the result?

Comment: This is in decimal, correct?  For given base $b$, the number written out as $1111\dots$ can be expressed as $b^n-1\over b-1$.  I do not know of any particular limit for any given base that guarantees that all values above that limit are composite...

Comment: These are [repunit primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit) and it has been conjectured that there are infinitely many of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [these](http://oeis.org/A004023) [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit#Decimal_repunit_primes) links; it is conjectured, but not known, that there are infinitely many decimal repunit primes, and similarly in many other bases.

When the base is an exponent, however, say $b = n^k$ with $n,k>1$, the repunits are $\frac{(n^k)^i-1}{n^k-1}$, and $(n^k)^i-1 = (n^i)^k-1$ can be factored into $\left[n^i-1\right]\left[(n^i)^{k-1}+(n^i)^{k-2}+\cdots+(n^i)+1\right]$, which gives a proper factorization of the $i^\text{th}$ repunit for sufficiently large $i$. So for example, 101 is the only repunit in base 100, that is, $10101, 1010101, 101010101, \cdots$ are all composite numbers.